# Thread safe rasterio writes from dask array store

Tags: python, gdal, dask, geotiff, rasterio

I'm trying to find the best/fastest way to save a dask array to a geotiff.

I've been doing research on how to make rasterio/GDAL thread-safe but I'm not coming up with anything that is easily accessible from **python**.

If I use `da.store(..., lock=False)` then the file can get corrupted.
I tried opening and closing the file for each write, but that still uses the same file descriptor (correct me if I'm wrong) and isn't a great solution anyway.

Does anyone have another way of doing this so that each dask worker (thread) can safely write to the **geotiff** file created by the **rasterio** library? The current working solution is to leave `dask.store` with its default of `lock-True`.

I'm guessing any other solution will involve thread locking anyway, but I thought it would be good to have this solution here anyway.

My working example code is below:

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.windows import Window


class RIOFile(object):
    """Rasterio wrapper to allow da.store to do window saving."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialize the object."""
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.rfile = None

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        """Put the data chunk in the image."""
        if len(key) == 3:
            indexes = list(range(
                key[0].start + 1,
                key[0].stop + 1,
                key[0].step or 1
            ))
            y = key[1]
            x = key[2]
        else:
            indexes = 1
            y = key[0]
            x = key[1]
        chy_off = y.start
        chy = y.stop - y.start
        chx_off = x.start
        chx = x.stop - x.start

        # band indexes
        self.rfile.write(item, window=Window(chx_off, chy_off, chx, chy),
                         indexes=indexes)

    def __enter__(self):
        """Enter method."""
        self.rfile = rasterio.open(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        """Exit method."""
        self.rfile.close()


rows = cols = 21696
a = da.ones((4, rows, cols), dtype=np.float64, chunks=(1, 4096, 4096) )
a = a * np.array([255., 255., 255., 255.])[:, None, None]
a = a.astype(np.uint8)

with RIOFile('test.tif', 'w', driver='GTiff', width=cols, height=rows, count=4, dtype=np.uint8) as r_file:
    da.store(a, r_file, lock=True)
```

Change `lock=False` for a probably corrupt file.

I've also been able to get successful, although not guaranteed, output by increasing GDAL's internal cache size.

Comment: Good luck with GDAL!  I'm curious, is there a problem to just continuing to use `lock=True`?  Is this a bottleneck in common applications?

Comment: @MRocklin the locking is probably not a bottleneck, but I haven't done comparisons. It was just a thought that multiple workers would benefit most from being able to write at the same time.

Comment: Actually did a quick test with the above code and it was actually faster with `lock=True` (15s versus 19s) so I guess it doesn't make a real difference.

Comment: Hooray for profiling!  Often the disk itself is the bottleneck, not having additional cores.